# NSMutable Array error with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I have this error but I don't see why it happens. The error only happens when I run the app on my iPad, in the simulator its fine.

I start off with

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("WeatherData")  != nil {

    WeatherData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("WeatherData") as NSMutableArray

    DisplayInfo(WeatherData[0] as String, Temperature: WeatherData[1] as Int, Code: WeatherData[2] as String, Condition: WeatherData[3] as String)
}
```

Then at the end I replace my WeatherData array and resave it.

```
WeatherData.replaceObjectsInRange(NSRange(0 ... 3), withObjectsFromArray: [placemark.locality, Temperature, Code, Condition])

}

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(WeatherData, forKey: "WeatherData")
```

the error I get is:

```
'-[__NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

I understand that my array is NSMutable but NSUserDefaults only accept immutable. What I wanted to do but didn't work:

```
WeatherData.replaceObjectsInRange(NSRange(0 ... 3), withObjectsFromArray: [placemark.locality, Temperature, Code, Condition]) as NSArray
```

Because I define my WeatherData Array initially as NSMutable. Would I need to create a new array as a placeholder?

Thanks in advance,
Ace

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` always returns immutable object. Make it like this

```
WeatherData = NSMutableArray(array: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("WeatherData"))
```